# JetBrains Rider show only one frame in stack when stop in breakpoint. How To fix this?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, stack-trace, jetbrains-ide, rider

We are using Rider 2020.1.3 with Unity 3D (2018.4.10)

Now when debugger stops in any breakpoint, Rider shows only one frame in stack trace

Everything used to be fine. At some point it became bad. Maybe this behaviour begun when I updated Rider last time (I'm not sure)

[image]

Invalidate Caches/Restart didnt help

Can you tell me please, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is to Uncheck the filter icon in the toolbar.
This issue is already fixed targeting Rider 2020.2.
https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/pull/1697